# MS Word Add-in constant has different values during start up (AutoExec)

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-addins

I am developing two Word Add-Ins that customize the ribbon.

The first one is on the local machine.

It contains an AutoExec sub to load the second add-in that is on a network drive:

```
Private Const AddInPath As String = "\\path\to\add\in"

Public Sub AutoExec()
    AddIns(AddInPath).Installed = True
    Call AddMenu
End Sub
```

The network add-in stores the name of the menu in a private const variable:

```
Private Const MENUNAME As String = "My Menu Name"
```

It contains the sub that adds the menu:

```
Public Sub AddMenu()
    Dim menu As CommandBar

    ' Ugly workaround for multiple menus 
    On Error GoTo Handler
    While True
        Application.CommandBars(TOOLBAR_NAME).Delete
    Wend
    Handler:
    'Just go on

    Set menu = Application.CommandBars.Add(MENUNAME)
    With menu
        ' [Do menu config]
    End with
End Sub
```

When Word starts, it executes the AutoExec Sub multiple times and adds the menu multiple times. I haven't figured why. As a workaround I delete the menu until there are no more of them (see ugly workaround section above).

My issue is that initially the menu was named "MyMenuName". Then I renamed it "My Menu Name" and it appears that Word executes pieces of codes with "MyMenuName" and others with "My Menu Name". As a result my menu is not clean: buttons are duplicated several times!

Comment: Have you tried setting a flag, to say `blnInstalling` or something similar and using this to only allow calling `AddMenu` if this flag is set to false?

Comment: Have you checked the Templates and Add-ins dialog to make sure that there aren't additional, old copies of the template loading? Are you sure none of the code is in your Normal.dotm?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav: I tried but I can't affect a default to the global flag variable :(! How would you do that?

Comment: @CindyMeister: In the Add-ins dialog the setting is correct (one local + one network add-ins). My Normal.dotm is empty in the VBA Editor. But Word asks me quite often to update it. This may be a good candidate but how can I check? Thanks!

Comment: @Plouff first answer on google is a good start https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-global-variables/